# Reachability Runtime error - SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue() failed: Permission denied

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

Here is my code:

```
Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:host];    
r.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread

    });
};    
r.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Update the UI on the main thread with error alert

    });
};    
[r startNotifier];
```

Upon running the last statement, I get following error logged, and it never executes any of the `reachableBlock` or `unreachableBlock`.

```
 SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue() failed: Permission denied
```

For anyone wanting to know what I tried already, I also attempted this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    [r startNotifier];
});
```

But this yields same result.
I logged an issue [here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/issues/44).

Comment: Use the Apple dev forums at http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Well as I wrote I am not sure if it's XCode that causes it. Looking at it, it seems definitely not something Apple can do anything about.

Comment: You are referring to software, which is under NDA by Apple and may only be discussed in their developer forums.

Comment: I confirmed that this is observed in XCode 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer an issue.

By some mysterious reasons, I cleaned up build folder, reset iOS simulator, relaunched it and recompiled - and the error is gone. I didn't succeed following these steps at first, but doing them just for the sake of trying, and it worked!